# in meteor how to stop functionalities to work at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

In meteor, I have created a cards dynamically after submitting the form. and the dynamic card contains the show and hide buttons. When I click on show option button the hidden part is showing for all the cards instead of that particular card. the problem is the card is creating dynamically so I thought that is problem .. how to  make the functionality to work separately to the each card.

Here I am attaching the code:

```
<div id="newActionCard">
    {{#each newaction}}
                 <div class="workflowcard">
                 <div class="module-card">
                     <div class="res-border"></div>
                    <div class="card-img"></div>
                    <div class="res-content">
                     <div class="  assigned-team">{{team}}</div>
                    <div class=" newaction-name">{{action_title}}</div><hr>
                    <div class="description">{{description}}</div>
                    <div class=" due-on">Due on:{{d_date}}</div><hr>
                    <div class="subcontent">
                        {{> actioncardsubcontent}} 
                     </div>
                     <div class="reqext">
                           {{> requestextensioncard}} 
                 </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="due">

                       Due on:
                        <div>
                            <span class="day-stamp">THU</span><br>
                        <div class="date-stamp">26</div>
                        <div class="month-stamp">AUG
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
     <div class="btn-box newaction">
      <button type="button" class="cancelsub" >New Action</button>
      <button type="submit" class="createbtnsub" >Show Options</button>
    </div>
     <div class="btn-box showoption">
      <button type="button" class="hideoption"  style="display:none">Hide Options</button>
      </div>

                {{/each}}                                                                                                                                              
        </div>
```

In JS I have written the hide and show functionalities in the events..now how to stop functionality to all cards at a time.

Here is my JS:

```
Template.workflow.events({

   "click .createbtnsub" : function() {
      $( ".subcontent" ).show();
     $('.createbtnsub').hide();
        $('.cancelsub').hide();
      $('.hideoption').show();
       $('.requestextension').show();

   },
   "click .hideoption": function(){
       $('.subcontent').hide();

   },



       "click .hideoption": function(){
         $(".subcontent").hide();
         $('.cancelsub').show();
         $('.createbtnsub').show();
         $('.requestextension').hide();
         $('.hideoption').hide();
         $('.reqext').hide();
     }, 



     "click #createActionBtn": function(){

         $('#createAction').hide();
         $('.editw').show();
         $('.hidew').show();
     },
});

Template.actioncardsubcontent.rendered = function(){
    this.$(".subcontent").hide();
};

Template.requestextensioncard.rendered = function(){
    this.$(".reqext").hide();

};

Template.workflow.helpers({
    getWorkflow: function(){
        return Workflow.find();
    },
    user: function(){
 return  Meteor.users.find({});
 },
 getNewaction: function(){
        return Newaction.find();
    },

});
```

Comment: Can you post your JS, as that is where the functionality is. However at guessing it is applying to all your cards it sounds like you have not invoked this, event.current.Target or an index reference. But after you post JS I'll know for sure .

Comment: I have attached my JS ..

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following and adjust the selectors as needed:

```
     "click .showoption": function(event){
        $(event.currentTarget).next('button').show();
     }
```

This will work for selecting sibling elements, however as a tip I would recommend rewriting your template.helper that returns the cards data from the database into something more specific.

Something like dynamic classes based on index or id so your class/id names would return as follows .showoption-12kjddfse4 . Then you can just get the attribute of the current target and apply it to your js selector.

Also as kind of an explination to why all buttons were showing, is you were using the class selector, which is meant for grabbing groups of elements/nodes.  This is also another reason to created more specific classnames/ids to your use case.

So in your class name you could do something like

```
<button class="showoption" id="{{_id}}">button</button>
<button id="hiddenoption-{{_id}}" class="hiddenoption">button</button>
```

Then selecting your elements would be easier as follows:

```
'click .showoption'(event) => {
   let id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute(id);
   document.getElementById('hiddenoption-'+id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Hhmm... I did test it. When you ran it, did the console comeback with an error?

Comment: Also did you try creating dynamic IDs or Classes as I suggested as a second option?

Could you separate the html button/link to be clicked and the hidden option to be shown away from the html that is not tied to the functionality. This will help clarify which buttons are specific to your question.

Comment: Ok I will attach the code properly and will be explaining clearly.. In console it shows the id is not defined. When I tried with above one.I have given the classes to generate the card dynamically when a form is submitted and given classes to the buttons as well.